# Notepad++ search & replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to convert a html file with 100 of entries like this one:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="30">
1.</td>
<td>
TEXT DESCRIPTION
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

where the number "1." goes from 1 to 100, into this:

```
<li>
   TEXT DESCRIPTION
</li>
```

I haven't find a way to do this, neither with regexp nor with extended search mode. Any ideas?

Comment: That HTML doesn't seem regular enough to be effectively parsed by regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with this:

Replace

```
.*<td>(.*[A-Za-z]+.*)<\/td>.*
```

with

```
<li>\1</li>
```

This will match one chunk of code of the form you reported. You must modify it to match multiple chunks of the same form in the same file.
Moreover to work correctly we should make it match lazily. Someone who knows how?

Comment: Not going to work - Notepad++ regexes work line by line only.

Comment: I saw. First you could remove all newline character, so you will get only one line.

Comment: So is the OP going to have to add back the newlines himself?